# Update Data in Files in Haskell

Tags: file, haskell, crud

i am learning about CRUD in haskell, but i get confuse to update data. so far this i have made, this is my data type

```
data ProjAdmin = RecordProjAdmin { projname :: String, animator :: String,
                             projstatus :: String} deriving (Show, Read)
```

this is data sample

```
thisData :: [ProjAdmin]
thisData = [RecordProjAdmin {projname = "SERIAL", animator = "jet juy", projstatus = "ongoing"},
           RecordProjAdmin {projname = "FIILER", animator = "jet juy", projstatus = "done"},
           RecordProjAdmin {projname = "RECYCLE-TVS", animator = "jet juy", projstatus = "done"}]
```

the logic here is, i want to change projname = "SERIAL" from "ongoing" status to "done", so next time i will set getLine input name "SERIAL". i still bit confuse to doing this either

```
filTering :: [ProjAdmin]->[ProjAdmin]
filTering = filter(\s-> projstatus s == "ongoing")
```

this is my main

```
main ::IO ()
main  = do
         let output = filTering thisData
         let changedata = map (\y -> if projstatus y=="ongoing" then projstatus y = "done" else projstatus y) output
         print changedata
```

if there's is any idea to create update function, i'll be so greatfull
thank you so much, or is it possible to using monad transformer to doing this? or if you know post that already answer or web link please let me know

thank you before

Comment: `if projstatus y=="ongoing" then projstatus y = "done"` That is completely wrong and contrary to how Haskell works. You should probably do a refresher on the fundamentals of the language.

Comment: Hi joseph thank you for your advise, i am just learning haskell...still adjusting....anw suggestion tutorial for learning kind case...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're pretty close! Here's a corrected version of the incorrect line:

```
let changedata = map (\y -> if projstatus y == "ongoing" then y { projstatus = "done" } else y) output
```

For your Googling pleasure, this is called "record update syntax".

Answer (score 0):

In Haskell all values are immutable, so to "update" some value you need to write a function that actually produces a new value based on the old one.

Here is an implementation of `filtering :: [ProjAdmin]->[ProjAdmin]` (if you really want this function to have this type):

```hs
filtering :: [ProjAdmin]->[ProjAdmin]
filtering inputs = map changeIfCond inputs

-- changes the value if its name is "SERIAL" and status is "ongoing"
changeIfCond :: ProjAdmin -> ProjAdmin
changeIfCond (RecordProjAdmin name anim status) =
    if name == "SERIAL" && status == "ongoing"
       then RecordProjAdmin name anim "done"
       else RecordProjAdmin name anim status
```

Of course, writing functions like these is tedious, so you might want to look on the "lenses" topic.

Comment: hi arrowd, thank you for your advise, i looking for lenses tutorial in youtube right now...

Comment: @skyhighdoor You'd be better served by spending more time reading documentation and less time watching YouTube tutorials.